# Cloning an encrypted HDD

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, encryption, luks

How can I easily clone an encrypted HDD that is running Ubuntu 16.04 with LUKS encryption? I want to be able to move my install from my current desktop to a laptop, so I can't just physically move my current HDD. I was thinking about using something like Clonezilla's live release but I'm not sure if this approach would would work on an encrypted HDD. My intended target HDD is larger than the source.

Comment: Clonezilla should be enough.

Comment: **first of all backup backup backup** - if you aren't using TPM, you can just clone it as encrypted, and then fix the disk header(?) using gparted because it will report disk size as the first disk, iirc gparted will show you a notice when it detects that. `dd` should be enough for cloning. after that, you can decrypt and resize the encrypted partition

Answer (score 0):

Clonezilla can easily and reliably clone any encrypted Ubuntu drive onto an equal or larger sized target.  Plenty of examples on how to do this.

As you go through the menu process in Clonezilla Live the key settings to be aware of are unclicking E2 and J2 and selecting K0.  Leave all other settings at their default.

A caveat is that if the target drive is larger than the source drive being cloned, any addition space on the target will not be used.  Example:  If the source is 500MB and the target is 1TB, cloning an encrypted filesystem will only consume 500MB of the 1TB drive.  It will not/cannot be expanded.

The above is not true when cloning source drives that do not use Ubuntu's LUKS encryption scheme.  Clonezilla will clone the source and expand the file system as expected.

To clone ***and expand*** a LUKS encrypted drive you would first need to unlock the filesystem which cannot be done using Clonezilla.

Alternately, you can accomplish your objective by decrypting your source HDD, cloning it to the laptop HDD/SDD and then (if desired) encrypt the target laptop drive using Trucrypt or some other tool.

Comment: I'm confused by these two statements which appear to contradict each other "Clonezilla can easily and reliably clone any encrypted Ubuntu drive" and "To clone and expand a LUKS encrypted drive you would first need to unlock the filesystem which cannot be done using Clonezilla."